# If condition fails if exception is thrown from inside if block

Tags: c#

In My application, I'm reading a config file and if the file is not available, throw an exception.

```
if (!File.Exists(configurationFile))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Configuration file is missing.");
}
```

What is happening here is even if the file exists, flow goes to throw statement. I also noticed that If I remove the throw statement from inside the if block, then this flow works correctly i.e. if file exist, control does not go inside the if block.

Has anyone faced this issue before? any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: I guess you are passing wrong file path in "configurationFile".

Comment: sounds like the current application-wide path is not what you think it is...

Comment: Try to find if the configuration path is correct using VS debugger.

Answer (score 6):

[File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) will return false for a number of reasons, not just necessarily if the file doesn't exist (which could explain why it still fails even if the file is there).

From MSDN:

> Returns true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the
>   name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns
>   false if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If
>   the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified
>   file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless
>   of the existence of path.

Comment: The remarks section in MSDN link for File.Exists explains it.

Answer (score 3):

> If I remove the throw statement from inside the if block, then this flow works correctly i.e. if file exist, control does not go inside the if block.

This must be a debugger / debugging malfunction.

Comment: I thought I was the only one "misunderstanding" the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified
>   file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless
>   of the existence of path.

So you must ensure that you are running your application under an account that has sufficient permissions.

Comment: [Sysinternal's Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) was helpful to me for similar scenarios in the past.